# How to rotate a line around one of its vertexes

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, raycasting, cartesian-coordinates

I am making my first raycasting engine, and would like to rotate a line over an angle θ

How does one do this? Would it be possible to show me some basic C++ code or some pseudocode?

This image describes my problem:
[image]

---

#### Optional question

I decided to make all of this in `graphics.h`, because it is the simplest graphics header for C/C++.

Comment: Also interested, because cross product works only in 3 dimensions

Comment: Link doesn't work, I get the image cannot be displayed.

Comment: It works for me :/

Comment: If you are doing linear algebra, pick a linear algebra library and express it using values of appropriate types. Then you can write code that looks like the maths `B = P + M * (A - P);` *can be* valid C++

Comment: This website can be of help to you: http://geomalgorithms.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
B = P + M * (A - P)
```

Where `M` is a 2D rotation matrix:

```
M = |  cos(ϴ)  -sin(ϴ) |
    |  sin(ϴ)   cos(ϴ) |
```

In C++ it could be written as:

```
float c = cos(theta), s = sin(theta);
float dx = ax - px, dy = ay - py;
float bx = px + c * dx - s * dy;
float by = py + s * dx + c * dy;
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple algorithm:

1. Move the circle `-P`, so that `P` is at (0, 0).
2. Rotate `A` by the angle by multiplying it by the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).
3. Move the circle `P` to restore its original position.

All these three steps can be done using one 3x3 matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

The scalar product of two vectors have the following property:

```
vec(PA) . vec(PB) = rho cos theta
```

Taking the definition of our two vectors:

```
vec(PA) = (x_a-x_p, y_a-y_p)
vec(PB) = (x_b-x_p, y_b-y_p)
```

We can get:

```
(x_a-x_p)(x_b-x_p) + (y_a-y_p)(y_b-y_p) = rho cos theta (1)
```

Since PA=PB, we also have:

```
(x_a-x_p)^2 + (y_a-y_p)^2 = (x_b-x_p)^2 + (y_b-y_p)^2 (2)
```

From `(1)` and `(2)` you can derive `x_b`and `y_b` with some arithmetic autopilot.